# Formatting number so that zeros are dashes (-) with xlwt

Tags: python, excel, number-formatting, xlwt

I'm writing excel sheets with xlwt, and it's working great except for one little thing. I would like to display the number zero as a dash (-), the way that it does with accounting. However, I don't want it to show the dollar sign, $, before everything, and I don't want it to have commas at the thousands.

I thought this would be a fairly easy problem to solve, I just go and set the format in excel to what I want, then view "Format -> Custom Format" to get the exact format string. Doing so gives me `_(* (#,##0);_(* "-"_);_(@_)` to use (this doesn't deal with the commas, but does display zeros as dashes and removes the $).
Unfortunately, when I use that string in xlwt, it seems to reset it to the accounting default: `_($* #,##0_);_($* (#,##0);_($* "-"_);_(@_)`. I think this is a bug in xlwt, but does anyone know if there's a way around this to let me do what I want to do?

Edit:
Don't know why it works, but my problem seems to be solved by removing the commas from the string. That is changing:

'_(* #,##0_);_(* (#,##0);_(* "-"*);*(@*)'
to
'*(* ###0_);_(* (###0);_(* "-"*);*(@_)'

I believe this works because xlwt doesn't see it as a custom format when you just remove the $ and instead writes as the accounting default, but when you remove the $ and the commas it kicks it into the custom format method, which is what I want.

In response to John, I'm using these with the tablestyle.numformat attribute. basic code would be:

```
style = xlwt.xlwt.XFStyle()
```

`style.num_format_str = '_(* ###0_);_(* (###0);_(* "-"_);_(@_)'`

The only thing I would ideally like to change now is make negative numbers appear like -5, rather than accounting (5), but I think I can live with how it is now. It might be nice if someone could explain how the excel format strings work though, I can see a bit of rhyme/reason in them but am mostly confused by these long string of numbers that I just cut and paste in.

Comment: "when I use that string in xlwt" tells us nothing. Edit your question to show the minimal code that will reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some minimal working code. In the output spreadsheet, column A is using your original format, B is using what you first appeared to be wanting (accounting format), and column C gives you non-accounting format.

```
import xlwt
custom_fmts = (
    '_(* (#,##0);_(* "-");(@)',
    '_(#0_);(#0);"-"_)', # positive;negative;zero
    '#0;-#0;"-"', # positive;negative;zero
    )
xfs = [xlwt.easyxf('', fmt) for fmt in custom_fmts]
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet('x')
for colx, xf in enumerate(xfs):
    for rowx, value in enumerate((1234567, 0, -1234567)):
        ws.write(rowx, colx, value, xf)

wb.save('demo_custom_format.xls')
```

You may like to read the tutorial that you can access via [this link](http://www.python-excel.org).

> It might be nice if someone could explain how the excel format strings
>   work

No good telling you to RTFM because there hasn't been a manual since about Excel 5.0 AFAIK but you can always HTF1K (hit the F1 key) then type `custom formats` into the search box and then FYN (follow your nose).